# siutable tool and technology for electronic health system?

Tags: java, php, asp.net

hello i am going to develop an EHR (Electronic Health Record System) i am new to this field and want to discuss and get the suggestion about what tool technology i have to use for this purpose:

here is my research about EHR and available tools for it

1) i am going to discuss about java as an EHR is a web based system so J2EE will be the solution for java at core level and as i am going to globalize my system so i need some standard protocol for it the most useful and appreciated one is `HL7 CDA 2.0` one thing about java i like is it provides `JAVA CAPS` with full implementation of HL7 protocol. it make my work bit easy the second thing about java is it is very efficient for `DATA CENTERED` application as mine one is but the problem is with the scalability of system that is much expensive and time taking. and java is bit slower on client side that can effect downtime that should me very less approaching to zero for my system. and at last i need a attractive user interface. and the most wanted thing is privacy and security.

2) the other option is `PHP`  for doing all as above described it is less expensive and less time taking for scalability,may contribute to achieve a good interface and a faster client side but question mark on data centric environment and security.

3) the last one is the MS's `ASP.NET` no doubt about security and privacy but very much expensive to develop and maintain and no platform independence and what about speed that is response and down times?

i have discussed the possibilities upto my best knowledge hope u people advise me which one will be the best to attain privacy, security, speed and scalability on best cost.

thanx in advance.

Comment: You are going to develop that, alone? And you are new to that business? Good luck with that.

Comment: This depends on what you are experienced with.

Comment: Mr. thanx for wishing me best of luck but i have support from experienced persons but this is my homework for next discussion i think you can understand what one have to do to jump in to new field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an EHR implementor since 1983, I'd suggest you look for a language that provides a user interface that allows multiple inputs including keyboard, mouse, touch,  voice and stylus, and potentially runs on multiple devices including phones and PCs.  The server side if written correctly should not offer scaleability issues.

As for HL7, you're going to use that server side anyway so I don't think it's relevant to how you write your clients.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by answering your actual question.  Any of those 3 languages could in principle be used for a large scale data-intensive application such as what you are considering.  You may find it marginally more expensive in PHP, but it will make little difference at the scale you are describing.

If I were developing a EHR system I would start by looking at the legal aspects of it, then build the actual requirements, which I imagine would be a massive undertaking.  Finally, I would just build it using whatever technology gave me access to a wide pool of skilled talent.  The language will only really effect what talent you can hire in on short notice.

I hope I'm not being presumptious here, but it would appear, just from your question, that you have little experience with programming, the design of large systems, healthcare, the applicable legal framework or running an ISV.  Do you have a compelling reason for entering this market?